# Gridview inline style

Tags: asp.net

I cannot figure this out.  I have always used CSS to set my gridview styles.  I need to export a gridview to word so I need to use inline styles to have the formatting passed to word.  Can someone help me convert the following CSS to a column HeaderStyle .

```
.AL_SubTotal_Row_1_RG
 {
    background-color:#77A78C; 
    font-weight:bold;
    border-right: 1px solid #8F8F8F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

I have this much of it done.  I do not know how to handle the individual borders.

```
 "<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="center" BackColor="#77A78C" BorderStyle="Solid" Font- bold="true />"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can have the flexibility of having different border for  bottom and right. Try this

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-BackColor="#77A78C" 
                HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
                HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid"
                HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" 
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

**Update:** Hope this work for your scenario

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(TableCell cell in xyz.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
        cell.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#77A78C; font-weight:bold; border-right: 1px solid #8F8F8F; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center;");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to be able to set the border-right and border-bottom individually